# How can I call the page I wanted to be the main page in my app in App.cs? I tried the Following code to call it but it did not show

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, shared

Here is how I call the page I wanted to be the first page/main page... I am using the "Blank App (Xamarin.forms Shared). You're reply is highly appreciated. I am very new to Xamarin and C#. Please Help.

```
MainPage = new FirstPage();
```

Comment: That's correct.  Do you get any errors or exceptions?  Are you sure that there isn't a problem with your FIrstPage that is causing it to display incorrectly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting at my post. Yeah, I finally found the very reason why it didn't show. In my FirstPage.xaml, I only removed that code <Label text="{Binding Text}" .../>, and after that, it works perfectly. But anyway, I really appreciate your reply @Jason.